# Volume UUID using IOKit framework from OS X

Tags: macos, uuid, volume, iokit

I want to get / enumerate UUID of of volumes mounted on my OS X system. 
I know that I can use diskutil command to get it as below.

```
$ diskutil info / |grep "Volume UUID"
   Volume UUID:              039B9653-52AA-34F3-AF4A-854FA47C811A
```

However, I want to achieve it in a programmable way (maybe) using IOKit framework. 
If anyone can tell me how to do it, it will be very helpful.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @pmdj's answer, I could solve my issue with the following code snippet.

```
void printUUID()
{
    DADiskRef disk;
    CFDictionaryRef descDict;

    DASessionRef session = DASessionCreate(NULL);

    std::string mountPoint = "/";
    CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation(NULL, (const UInt8 *) mountPoint.c_str(), mountPoint.length(), TRUE);
    disk = DADiskCreateFromVolumePath(NULL, session, url);
    if (disk) {
        descDict = DADiskCopyDescription(disk);
        if (descDict) {
            CFTypeRef value = (CFTypeRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(descDict,
                                                              CFSTR("DAVolumeUUID"));
            CFStringRef strValue = CFStringCreateWithFormat(NULL, NULL,
                                                            CFSTR("%@"), value);
            printf("%s\n" ,CFStringGetCStringPtr(strValue, kCFStringEncodingMacRoman));
            CFRelease(strValue);
            CFRelease(descDict);
        }
        CFRelease(disk);
    }

    CFRelease(url);
    CFRelease(session);
}
```

Comment: Glad you got it working! Don't forget to `CFRelease(session);` (I realise you're probably already doing that in your real code, just not in the copy-pasted one here.)

Comment: @pmdj I modified the snippet as you recommended that a lot for your help again!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the [Disk Arbitration framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DriversKernelHardware/Conceptual/DiskArbitrationProgGuide/ManipulatingDisks/ManipulatingDisks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009310-CH3-SW1)? This is much better suited for volume enumeration, mount operations, etc., and allows you to query UUIDs among other properties., You can retrieve the IOService handle to the underlying IOKit objects as well, should you need them.

Note that both the HFS+ file system and the GPT partition on which it resides will have a UUID, and they will not match. diskutil generally talks about the HFS+ UUID.

Comment: Oh. I didn't know that. I will have a look. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There's a simpler way to get the UUID from a path that doesn't have to use the Disk Arbitration framework. The code below returns the volume UUID of the input full item path, using the NSURL's getResourceValue and the NSURLVolumeUUIDStringKey:

```
    NSURL* pathUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSString* volumeUUID = nil;
    NSError* error = nil;
    BOOL success = [pathUrl getResourceValue:&volumeUUID forKey:NSURLVolumeUUIDStringKey error:&error];
```

Note that it does not enumerate the UUIDs of the mounted volumes, just gives you the volume UUID of the input path.